# Поиск подстроки в строке с помощью char

Tags: c++, строки, char, подстрока

Задание: Нужно произвести поиск вещественного числа с фиксированной точкой в строке. И реализовать это через массив символов.

Снизу приведен пример выполнения с помощью string. Прошу помочь с такими вопросами: Как объявить строку в char? Найти её длину, учитывая ,что строка вводится с клавиатуры?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath> 
#include<conio.h> 
#include<string> 
using namespace std;
int main(int args, double, char * argv[]) {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int c, o, t, u, v, n = 0;
int f = 0;
int b = 0;
int m = 0;
o = 0;
u = 0;
t = 0;
string sr; 
cout << "Введите строку" << endl;
getline(cin, sr); 
for (int i = 0; i < sr.length(); i++) {
if (sr[i] == '.') { 
    if (!(isdigit(sr[i + 1])) || !(isdigit(sr[i - 1]))) { 
        continue;
    }
    else {
        for (v = i - 1; v > 0; v--) { 
            if (isdigit(sr[v])) {
                b = v;
            }
            else {
                if (sr[v] == '-') {
                    b = v;
                    break;
                }
                else break;
            }
        }
        for (f = b; f < sr.length(); f++) {
            if (sr[f] == '.') {
                break;
            }
            if (sr[f] == '-') {
                continue;
            }
            o++;
        }
    }
    f = 0;
    for (int n = i + 1; n < sr.length(); n++) {
        if (isdigit(sr[n])) {
            m = n;  
        }
        else break;
    }
    for (f = m; f > 0; f--) {  
        if (sr[f] == '.') {
            break;
        }
        u++;
    }
}
}
if (o == u) {
c = 0;
}
else {
c = 1;
}
if (c == 0 && t == 0) {
cout << "Число = ";
for (int i = b; i <= m; i++) {
    cout << sr[i];
}
}
else {
cout << "такого числа нет";
}
cout << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Для начала вам придеться выделить память под строку, при этом, если не можете знать размер строки заранее, то придеться организовать цикл с проверкой, в котором при вводе строки больше буфера, придеться осуществлять конкатенацию строк, ну и, сасо собой, нужно ограничить количество плучаемых символов размером буфера - 1. Ну а после завершения считывания, найти ее длину уже не составит труда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ясно, что перед обьявлением массива, нужно определять размер введенной строки. Для этого нужно выделять память под строку с большим размером, а потом определить размер:

```
char* p = new char[256];
std::cin.getline(p, 255);
const size_t array_size = strlen(p);
char array[array_size + 1];
strcpy(array, p);
//если не нужно вводить еще одну строку, то
delete p;
```

И используйте  `array` и его размер `array_size`